# How Can I Reference Multiple Primary Keys For A Vector Type Primary Key

Tags: sql

I have the following scenario: a table of projects and a table of persons, working on one or several projects. Also, I have a project id column (of type int), in the first table, which is a primary key there and I have a vector of project ids, as a column of type int, in my second table (persons), that references primary keys from the first table.

What is the correct syntax for referencing multiple primary keys, from a vector foreign key.
This is the way I am trying to create the table, but I am not sure what to place at the indicated line:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
    Person_Id int,
    ...,
    ProjectsList int[],
    FOREIGN KEY (ProjectsList) REFERENCES Projects(Project_id) -- not sure what how to define the link here
);
```

I hope my explanations are not over-complicated. Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using PostgreSQL, since that's one of the rare databases that supports array data types.

There is no syntax for declaring a foreign key that applies to the elements of an array.

You could write a trigger or a `CHECK` constraint as mentioned [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2005-10/msg00149.php).

But the better solution is to add a table to implement the many-to-many relationship between Projects and Persons, as Lukáš Lalinský shows.  This supports [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 1):

No database I know can do that (using real foreign keys, not some custom triggers). You might want to normalize the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  Person_ID int,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PersonProjects (
  Person_ID int,
  Project_ID int,
  PRIMARY KEY (Person_ID, Project_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Person_ID) REFERENCES Persons(Person_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Project_ID) REFERENCES Projects(Project_ID)
);
```

Comment: That's *normalizing* the tables!

Comment: Meh, it's obviously too late for me to answer questions. :)